# FirebaseApp is not initialized

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have encounter weird Firebase initialization problem on my application recently.
I am using Android Studio Chipmunk(2021.2.1 Patch 1). Application can be build normally and installed to device on **debug mode without any error** but ***if you install an APK directly (or download from app distribution) app gets the error during app init***.

My google-services.json file is under the src/ and its last recent version.

```
2022-06-08 23:57:44.570 13535-13535/com.example.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app.debug, PID: 13535
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.app.debug.commons.application.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.app.debug. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6739)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2090)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Top level gradle plugin part:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}
```

App level build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
```

Comment: new version of the google-services library makes the initialization automatically and you dont need to call initializeApp() separately if you dont connect multiple firebase apps. And also it can find&use the json file in src/ folder directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new gradle plugin and wrapper apk output directory and apk is different than each other. Looks like something is broken or not compatible with current google-services (v4.3.10) dependency

- (WORKING)gradle-wrapper 7.2, application&library 7.1.3 -> ./app/build/intermediates/apk/google/debug
- (GETS ERROR AT THE TOP)gradle-wrapper 7.3.3, application&library 7.2.1 -> ./app/build/outputs/apk/google/debug

Solution: **Use working versions for wrapper and platform.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disconnect the project from the Firebase and reconnect again the project to Firebase. In my case is like this, I have done it and it's successful in my Android project. Thank you.

Comment: it was a case related with wrapper&platform version. Google play services library is too sensitive for this update. I will double check firebase integration after that update next time. :) So First comment was the accepted answer for my case :)

Comment: In general, a "try and restart" comment is of very low quality and will general get downvoted